# Problem while trying to setup Linux OpenSuse from USB Disc

Tags: linux, grub2, dual-boot, opensuse

I've got a Lenovo IP Z500 notebook with Windows 7 installed & I'm trying to setup OpenSuse alongside Windows. I burnt an .ISO image containing Leap 42.20 (I got it from the official site) on my USB memory. Now when I try to boot from USB in order to start setup, only a GRUB command prompt appears. I tried a bunch of commands like: setup, boot, reboot, kernel, exit, etc. which were useless at this point.

According to SUSE installation manual, I am supposed to receive a green graphical setup menu and not a simple command prompt.

I have also read some similar discussions. In one of them, it was mentioned that Secure-Boot must be turned-off. I found nothing like a secure-boot option under security tab in BIOS menu. There was just one menu in there with two options: Legacy support (Default) and UEFI. I switched between them, yet stuck in that GRUB command prompt. Any help, please?

Comment: did you check md5 of image that you downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that means Grub2 has not found the bootloader.
Reasons are:

- Problem in the downloaded iso as @darvark has mentioned
- The iso file was not burned properly

As you are probably using Windows, download [ImageUSB](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html) and burn the iso again.

I have installed openSUSE Tumbleweed from USB recently with UEFI activated and there were no problems, but if it does not work try to activate `Legacy Support` in your Bios setup.